# How does a cable tone-and-probe kit work?

Tags: signal, tools, probe

A useful tool for someone installing electrical cabling of any sort can be a **Tone and Probe Tool**: it allows one to find individual leads among a possibly hundreds in a cable trunk, without having to either strip or connect the remote end.

[image: Pitch Generator from Wikipedia]

With the *tone generator* part connected to the start of the wire(-s), the *probe tool* typically generates an audible tone once its tip is in close proximity of the correct wire.

Can someone explain how these work in theory, perhaps with a high-level sketch of the basic circuits of such a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tone generator injects a signal onto the cable to be traced. Typically it's a Square wave (with high harmonic content), or a warbling tone.

Here's an example:

[image]

The probe tool is usually called an Inductive Amplifier, but in reality it works by capacitive coupling from the tone injected onto the wire.

There's a very informative [Google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!search/inductive$20amplifier$20Lizard$20Blizzard/sci.electronics.misc/45uOtiyUFI0/qNhDqdzEUL4J) on this, where the probe is described as:

> The original 'banana' probe is simply a LM386 driving a mini 1" (25 mm)
>   to 1.3" (30 mm) speaker.  The input has an MPF102 JFET as a source
>   follower, with a 4.7k source load resistor and a 10 meg from gate to
>   ground (& collector to +9V).  A 47 pf cap in parallel with the 10 M to
>   rolloff highs, and a 1 Meg in series between the gate and probe tip.
>   The source load resistor is coupled to the input of 386 thru a .1 uF
>   ceramic cap.  A push button momentary contact switch and 9V battery
>   complete the circuit.

[This site](http://www.epanorama.net/newepa/2013/03/05/cable-tracing-inductive-amplifier/) describes one guys attempt at building one.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the explanation and those links, very much informative and on the subject!